# interruption processing - the global variable value doesn't changed in function c++

Tags: c++, interruption

i had change the global variable value in interrupt vector function, but this value doesn't transfered into the function or the function doesn't read the changed value, which is changed by the interruption vector.
the vector interruption itself is

```
                   //---------------------------------------------
     ISR(INT1_vect)
     {
     EIMSK |= !(1<<INT1);   //disable    int1   âíåøíèå ïðåðûâàíèÿ INT0
     _delay_ms(900);
     switch(Ok)
        {
            case 0: MenuOut();break;
            case 1: endFunction=1;break;
            //case 1: EndFunction(endFunction,Ok);break;  //1st var -doesnt print changed value ok and endFunction
            default:break;
            //case 20:Ok=0;MenuPrint();break;
        }
     //EIMSK |= (1<<INT1); add this line 2 func 2 enable
     }
    //---------------------------------------------
```

and the function itself is look like this (i had removed excessed details,            just significant cycle less)
the idea is if the function is launched, the flag OK=1, and in this case the interruption processing function change value of the variable endFunction and it's value is checked at the start of every cycle, and by default is 0, so when it changed by the interrupt  to 1, the cycle must to break, but really it continues before completing.

and the full text of function is below, in real it had some more operators
which are not significant for the question, but all the function has properly works, except the cycle breaking.

```
//--------------------  Adc  START  -----------------------------------------------
void Adc (void)  // dummy of Adc for the interrupt check only, later change to full power Adc,it's for screen output only
    //void Adc (volatile unsigned char endFunction,volatile unsigned char Ok)  //read the first 2 cells in array symbol[ ]
{
    Ok=1;  //button action flag - function is active//endFunction=0; //fla
    unsigned char j=0,n=0; //cycle counter
    Clearscreen();
    EIMSK |=(1<<INT1); //add this line 2 func 2 enable intrrpt
    while(j<100)
        {   
            //endFunction=0; //by default
            //----------------------check that pressed the select button ---------------------------------
            if (endFunction==1){break;}
            //if (Ok==1){MenuOut(); break;}
            //---------------------------------------------------
            while(n<6) // this cycle just repeat existing value measured before, n times for the  screen filling 
            {
                unsigned char m = 0;
                SetPgAddr(n,n+1);
                SetClmAddr((n*2),100);
                while (m<6)
                {
                    unsigned char a = 78-47; //my table symbol number is less than ascii 2 47
                    if ((a <1)|(a>10))
                    {
                        a=17;  //@
                    }
                    Char1(a);
                    m++;
                    _delay_ms(500);
                    
                }
                    //+1 is for 2 down 2 one line in my sym table
                    Char1(endFunction+1);Char1(Ok+1);
                    // :    26      0
                    // 0    16      1    ascii48
                    // 1    17      2
                    // .    26      11
                    // C    35      20  
                n++;//p2=p3=0;
                _delay_ms(100);
            }
            //-------------------------------------------   
            j++;Char1(13);  //for new edition identificator symbol - 
        }
        Ok=0;endFunction=0; //initialisation on out - button action flag - function is un active      
}
//-----------Adc FINISH -------------------------------------------------------
```

as for the variable declaring, i had declared is as global in first lines of main.c file, it looks like this:

```
// ---------------global --------------------------------
unsigned char a0;
unsigned int adc_value=0;
unsigned int adt_value=0;
unsigned char ColPosSt = 0;
unsigned char ColPosEnd = 127;
volatile  unsigned char endFunction=0;  //for the cancel - flag
volatile unsigned char Ok=0;  //for menu choice //button action flag - function is active
unsigned char PgPosSt = 0;
unsigned char PgPosEnd = 7;
unsigned char sec=0;
unsigned char zer =0;

unsigned char Line = 0; //for menu choice



//WARNING: This Font Require X-GLCD Lib.
//         You can not use it with MikroE GLCD Lib.
```

Comment: A delay in an interrupt service routine?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. The shown code accesses undefined identifiers. Gnerally, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You haven't posted declaration of your variables and the code that reads value of that variable.
However my guessing is you forgot about `volatile` keyword in declaration and optimization is an answer why the code sees old value ;)

Comment: i had posted the variables declaration below my main post, and it's volatile. it reads in the statement about 20 line of the code , in statement  `if (endFunction==1){break;}`  inside the `while` cycle, but about optimisation i didn't understand - would u  like to explain, which i need to change, for the sample?

Comment: @Yunnosch  the delay is for the button dribbling.  it works, but after function is completed only. or what are u mean about delay?

Comment: I interpreted (guessing of course) `_delay_ms(900);` as being a 900 ms delay within the ISR. That struck me as a strange real time design. But even if I am right with my guessing, it does not mean that it has to cause any trouble. I am just used to tighter timing needs.

Comment: @Yunnosch just for approving it's so long. but even if i make it's shorter (300ms) nothing happened, it still end function after complete only.

Comment: Perhaps it is some problem in the logic. How often and when is ADC() called?

Comment: @Sebastian the Adc is called one time by the interruption of the  button, and works constantly continious. the logic is simple:  It's Adc() function  is for measuring,and works forever (100 times or endless) and if i want to leave measuring, i give one more interrupt, and it check, if the flag Ok==1, it means that function is already has been launched,   it has change endFunction flag to 1 and it must be interrupted because of checking it's state in every while cycle. After function has end, these flags are both initialized.

Comment: So 100 times is not too short to notice, but the inner loop is short enough that endFunction is probed often enough?

Comment: If you change if (endFunction==1){break;} to if(j == 10)break;, it breaks?

Comment: the button interrupt has launched the Menuout() function, and it has launched the Adc() function, or any, which was previously choose

Comment: And you confirmed the button interrupt still works during the run of the Adc function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240719/discussion-between-ant-and-sebastian).

Answer (score 1):

You passed endFunction by value:

`void Adc (volatile unsigned char endFunction,volatile unsigned char Ok)              //read the first 2 cells in array symbol[ ] {`

it is a local variable (copy of argument you give calling that function) so interrupt routine doesn't even know about it. You need access directly global endFunction variable or pass it as e.g. pointer.

Comment: i had declared these as global, of coarse. In start lines of the program.

Comment: But here you have another variable with the same name (endFunction) created on stack during call :)

Comment: so, explain please, which i need to change? before the function call was looked as void Adc (void) {function body} and same did not work, so i add declaring as u see now. would u like to show the sample,please?

Comment: Don't pass the globals as arguments or if you do need to pass them as arguments pass them by reference or change their names so you can still access the globals

Comment: are u mean that i need return back to such function prototype as [ void Adc (void)] ?   because i had added arguments after it was not work in this form?

Comment: Yes, it is one of the possible solutions, you may have Adc(void) and find why it doesn't work. Like delays or sth.

Comment: `void Adc (void) `   i had changed the head of the function like this, but it same not saw, that endFunction value was changed by the interruption vector.  Are the interruption processing i was had properly wrote?

Comment: How does the interrupt handler 'see' the endFunction? Make sure there is not a similar problem (it sees a copy). Can you run the code with a debugger? Can you make sure that the address of the endfunction is the same in both functions, can you make sure that endFunction is changed in the interrupt routine? Can you tell something about the system: which CPU/architecture, single or multi-core? E.g. with multi-cores and wrongly configured cache, the change of variables may not be visible, etc. [hopefully not in your case]

Comment: @Sebastian really, not in my case: this is MCU system, and i cun't use a debugger for it, because of _delay's function, and unfortunately i don't know yet, how to emulate interrupt? i use for it just screen output only.  my IDE is Atmel 7.0 and this is 8bit MCU Atmega328.   and what about to check are the endFunction value is changed? if program has a statement , i guess it was executed? otherwise compilator would give me the error message? about a copy  - how can i to check (it's declared as global)?